# Html within Php foreach loop

Tags: php, html, loops

I am new to PHP. I have a function which returns an HTML code to my other function. That HTML code has some PHP code in it as well. The problem is I don't know how can I add a for loop in that HTML code and then return the whole HTML.

for example here is my code :

```
<?php
class Dummy
{
    public static function testing($data)
    {

        return '<div class = "dummy">name:' . $data['name'] . '</div>';


    }
}
?>
```

I want to insert foreach loop in it for example

```
<?php
    class Dummy
    {
        public static function testing($data)
        {

            return '<div class = "dummy">name:' . $data['name'] . '</div>
  <table>
      foreach($data as $d){
        <tr><td>hello</tr></td>
  }
            <table>

';


        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: well my question is to how can I add for loop in an HTML code which is being embedded in PHP code and that has nothing to do with the classes

Comment: Whoops my bad, I didn't notice the second class had a foreach in it. The formatting makes it appear as just HTML and I just blanked it out completly!

Comment: `foreach()` isnt client-side nor can you pass it as a string.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript no worries. thank you though for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first build your string with desired outout. Then return that string

```
<?php
    class Dummy
    {
        public static function testing($data)
        {

          $str = '<div class = "dummy">name:' . $data['name'] . '</div>
  <table>';

            foreach($data as $d){
                 $str .= '<tr><td>hello</td></tr>';
            }
          $str .= '</table>';
          return $str;



        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please update the closing tag for tr and table @B. Desai

Comment: i fail to see the point of the `foreach()`. the `$d` is not used

Comment: I have just provide demo of OP asked for. May be he know how to update it later to use foreach variables. @Akintunde007

Comment: Glad to help @mynameisbutt

Answer (score 1):

You can't really have a `for` loop within a return statement like that. You should make a variable to hold the string, and build it up within the loop as in this example:

```
public static function testing($data) {
    $html = '<div class = "dummy">name:' . $data['name'] . '</div>';
    $html .= '<table>';
    foreach($data as $d){
        $html .= '<tr><td>hello</td></tr>';
    }
    $html .= '<table>';
    return $html;
}
```

I would like to point out however that building HTML like this is generally a bad idea and you should use a templating language as is provided with most frameworks.

In PHP, the `.=` syntax is shorthand for concatenating a string. You could also use `$html = $html . '<p>some other content</p>';`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

create  before return

```
        <?php
    class Dummy
    {
        public static function testing($data)
        {
            $return='<div class = "dummy">name:' . $data['name'] . '</div><table>';
            foreach($data as $d){
                $return+='<tr><td>hello</td></tr>';
            }
            $return+='<table>';

            return $return;


        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -3):

As an example, you can do it like this.

```
<?php
        class Dummy
        {
            public static function testing($data, $x)
            {
                      $firstLine = '<div class = "dummy">X Value:' . $x . '</div>';
                      $firstLine .= '<div>';
                      $innerHtml = '';
                      foreach($data as $d) {
                            $innerHtml  .=    '<tr><td>hello '.$d['name'].'</td></tr>';      
                      }
                      $innerHtml = '<table>'.$innerHtml.'</table>';
                      $lastLine = "</div>";   
                      return  $firstLine.$innerHtml.$lastLine;

            }
        }

    $data[0]['name'] = "Nishant";
    $data[1]['name'] = "Amit";
    $data[2]['name'] = "Rachit";

    echo Dummy::testing($data, "This is X Value");
     ?>
```

Comment: I think, he wanted to know how he can create dynamic HTML content within foreach loop and return it. The same I did. I took different variables and concatenated them just to let him understand more clearly.

Comment: did you think you give more clear explanation for your code?

Comment: Yes, you can say this that I didn't provide explanation :) But, Questioner asked the same thing.

Comment: There isn't any explanation on how the code will work. It's worth adding explanation when you add extra lines compared to what questioner asked!